# Flutter Firestore cache stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter chat that displays newest messages when the user arrives at the end of the list.

This is done by setting a listener on the firestore, with a limit of 10 messages (limit (10)), and when I reach the end of the message list I increase the limit of the stream by 10.

```
// LISTENER QUERY MESSAGES

limitdocuments = 10;

StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('groups')
            .document(groupId)
            .collection("messages")
            .orderBy('sentTime', descending: true)
            .limit(limitdocuments)
            .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor)));
                } else {

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        buildItem(index, snapshot.data.documents[index],true)
                    },
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    reverse: true,
                    controller: listScrollController,
                  ); 

                }
             },
           ),
```

```
// END OF THE LIST, INCREASE THE LIMIT BY 10

if(listScrollController.position.atEdge){
    if(listScrollController.position.pixels == 0){
        setState(() {
            limitdocuments= limitdocuments+ 10;
        });
    }
}
```

**My question is, does firestore re-download all messages from the database ( including old messages ) or old ones are taken from the cache?**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First of all**

- Ensure that your stream is called in `initState()` so that you are certain that it's just called upon widget instantiation. Otherwise, it will always attempt to create new set of streams.

**Next is to test**

Try printing logs manually to see if the behavior you're expecting is correct.

```
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
   DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(i);

   // Check manually if the data you're referring to is coming from the cache.
   print(doc.metadata.isFromCache ? "Cached" : "Not Cached");
}
```

**Lastly, yes--it's supposed to be cached.**

From the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

As far as I know, Flutter Firestore or Realtime Database plugins should follow the same architecture and behavior we have for the native and web counterpart SDKs.

Comment: literally 'ALL' of the tutorials I have seen on Providers and Builders were sending the value stream directly in the build method! Not sure why its the case considering how bad of a practice it can become. Thanks for the answer! One follow up, will this method work if im switching tabs using setState() on the parent widget? So essentially the Provider is called inside a widget that is rebuilt by setState() on tab button click.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is generally correct, the docs now state:

> By default, no event is raised if only the SnapshotMetadata changed.
> **If you rely on the fromCache values, specify the
> includeMetadataChanges listen option when you attach your listen
> handler.**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#dart

```dart
db
    .collection("cities")
    .where("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true) // <---- HERE
    .listen((querySnapshot) {
  for (var change in querySnapshot.docChanges) {
    if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
      final source =
          (querySnapshot.metadata.isFromCache) ? "local cache" : "server";

      print("Data fetched from $source}");
    }
  }
});
```